# How to modify existing values in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

Below is a sample data set

```
 year  month  area     employment
 2020   09    000001      105
 2020   10    000001      105
 2020   09    123444      108
 2020   09    123444      109
```

It needs to look like this

```
  year  month  area     employment
 2020   09    000003      105
 2020   10    000003      105
 2020   09    123400      108
 2020   09    123400      109
```

The reason is that I have two rows of data per area but some areas have two names. 000001 and 000003 are the same. Floundering a bit trying to find out how to do this in R. In SQL, you would you use update and then set area = '000003' where .....

This seems simple but not sure what to look for when searching the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
df$area[df$area==000001]<-000003
df$area[df$area== 123444]<-123400
```

where df is your dataframe.